# Is it wise to process all forms on a single url?

Tags: php, forms, agile

is it ok to simply point all forms action to a single url and seprate them with a input_hidden for example form_id?
for example we create a url like: /process
and point all forms on that url , and there we seprate forms by a hidden counter

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no harm in doing that, but if you make different files than it will make a lot easier for anyone to understand.Making different files and calling them will make your code look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not wise. Separate unrelated functionality to different files, and call those, it makes it easier to see where is what. Lots of small files > One huge file.

Answer (score 0):

A few is typically OK, but only if you have lots of different forms on the same page and you aren't using Ajax to submit them.  The way you keep it tidy is by giving the forms names, and namespacing each field with that name so you know which form has been submitted.

This is often necessary in this case to reduce the work needed to load form validation errors, whereas you would normally need to keep the errors in the session to reload after a redirect from the processing page.

Example:

```
-> contact.php
    -> Submit to contact.php
        -> If errors, re-render the form without redirect on contact.php
        -> Else, process the form, then redirect.
```

In the event of errors, the second showing of the form would be part of the POST request, meaning you still have easy access to the previously submitted data.

If it was valid, you no longer need the posted data as you have already persisted it elsewhere.

This is highly contextual however.  It is not a reason to use a single script to process "all" of your forms.  Only the ones on the active page.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no.

But there are use cases where it's desirable to do it, at least for some forms. But these forms must implement the same interface, their behaviour is the same.

For example I have one use case where buttons are placed on page, each loads a different form in a modal. Each is posted to the same controller, but all the controller needs to know is that it calls `validate()`, `save()`, and `render()` methods on the form.

I'm sure there are other cases, but your general stand should be "no", unles you have a good reason for it.